# Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

Went from angular 5 to 6(using angular 6 & rxjs 6), getting the following two errors in my linter. Anybody have any ideas, please and thank you.

```
[ts] 'catchError' is declared but its value is never read.
[ts] Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
```

```ts
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(authReq)
      .catchError((error, caught) => {
        console.log('Error Occurred');
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }) as any;
  }
}
```

Comment: Something worth reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more of a change with rxjs. You'll want to familiarize yourself with lettable operators, but heres the code change you'll want to make...

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(authReq)
      .pipe(catchError((error, caught) => {
        console.log('Error Occurred');
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      })) as any;
  }
}
```

Pretty easy right! Most of the rxjs operators are now passed into the `pipe` function of the observable!

Comment: `Observable.throw` -> `throwError`.

Comment: throwError -> throw